# PrivateBinPath outside ApplicationBase

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, appdomainsetup

My directory structure looks like this:

```
-- Host Program Base
  |- HostProgram.exe
  |- SharedLIB.dll
  |-- LoadedLibs
     |- HostedLib.dll
```

`HostProgram.exe` is attempting to load `HostedLib.dll`, which depends on `SharedLib.dll`.

Thus, `SharedLib.dll`'s `ApplicationBase` for the `AppDomain` I am creating to load it is `/Host Program Base/HostedLibs/`, but it needs to be able to find `SharedLib.dll`.

I have tried to add `..` to the `PrivateBinPath` for the `AppDomain` but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath.aspx),

> Private assemblies are deployed in the same directory structure as the application. If the directories specified for PrivateBinPath are not under ApplicationBase, they are ignored.

As the `PrivateBinPath` is not inside the `ApplicationBase`, but rather is one directory up, it is not inside `ApplicationBase` and is being ignored. Therefore I get a `AssemblyResolveException` when attempting to load the DLL into the new `AppDomain`.

I have also attempted to set the `ApplicationBase` to the `Host Program Base` folder and add `HostedLibs` as a `PrivateBinPath`, but this causes the domain to be unable to resolve `HostedLib.dll` at all.

So -> **how do I resolve libraries outside `ApplicationBase` using an `AppDomainSetup`**?

Comment: I don't get the problem.  Keep the ApplicationBase at the EXE directory, make the PrivateBinPath the subdirectory.

Comment: The DLL file that has the dependency is in the subfolder "HostedLibs". Thus, the ApplicationBase MUST be "HostedLibs". @HansPassant

Comment: That's the point, I have no idea why you think that's necessary.  Have you at least tried it?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes I have tried it. I get an unresolved error for the HostedLib.dll when attempting to load it while the ApplicationBase is set one directory up and PrivateBinPath is set to "LoadedLibs"

Comment: This is an XY question.  Y won't work, we have no idea what might cause X.  Re-ask the question and document X properly. Post a code snippet and the failed bind log you get from Fuslogvw.exe

Comment: @HansPassant I have no idea what a bind log is but I will look it up. I think it's clear why it cannot resolve the assembly: it is not within `ApplicationBase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of reorganizing your application structure, you could use the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx)

Basically works like this.

1. Subscribe to the AssemblyResolve event on the AppDomain.
2. When the event fires, you can specifically look for your SharedLib.dll or simply attempt to create a full path to the desired assembly in your root folder given the assembly name specified in the [`ResolveEventArgs.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resolveeventargs.name.aspx) and use [`Assembly.LoadFrom(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx).
3. If the assembly successfully loaded from the path, return it in the [AssemblyResolve handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resolveeventhandler.aspx), otherwise return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented solution based on Jim's answer:

```
internal static class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve;
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        //Do your stuff
    }

    private static Assembly CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

            string expectedFileName = name.Name + ".dll";
            string rootDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            return LoadAssembly(rootDir, expectedFileName, "", "Dlls", "../Dlls");
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Assembly LoadAssembly(string rootDir, string fileName, params string[] directories)
    {
        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(rootDir, directory, fileName);
            if (File.Exists(path))
                return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```